# How to download all OSM data within a boundingbox with Overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, api, overpass-api

Is it possible to download openstreetmap by direct link through `http://overpass-turbo.eu` without removing any data?

Basically I am trying to download the openstreetmap data with defined boundaries in the same way that it is currently possible through openstreetmap.org:

```
http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=11,50,11.1,50.1
```

It's just the output should be .geojson instead of of .osm.

I am not sure I understand the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) syntax.
I need something similar to this:

```
[out:json];
node(11,50,11.1,50.1)
out body;
```

But how should I make the download link from it (assumed the upper syntax is correct, which it isn't)?

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data= [out:json](48,11,48.19,11.73)... ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [Overpass API Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide). Basically you seem to want [all data in a bounding box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Usage_examples:_All_data_in_a_bounding_box). Depending on your use-case you might want to download nodes, ways and relations.

[overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) already has a preset for this. Just go to *Load* and select *Map Call*. The resulting query is:

```
[out:xml];
(
  node({{bbox}});
  <;
);
out meta;
```

Change `xml` to `json` to change the [output format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Choose_file_format_.28ouput.3Djson.2C_.5Bout:json.5D.29). This corresponds to the following Overpass API query:

[http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node(11,50,11.1,50.1);<;);out meta;](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3B%28node%2811%2C50%2C11%2E1%2C50%2E1%29%3B%3C%3B%29%3Bout%20meta%3B%0A)

However json is just json and *not* geojson. There are various converters around on the Internet though. overpass turbo also includes one if you go to *Export*.

Remember that overpass turbo is just a front-end to Overpass API, usually you don't really need it except for playing around and visualizing the results.

For larger areas consider downloading one of the [country or area extracts](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Extract#Country_and_area_extracts).

Comment: Thank you again for the reply @scai.
Ah, I was not aware of the fact that json is not the same as geojson. Thank you. I can not click on ```Export``` I need direct link download.
How do I get the direct download link for the syntax you gave me?
To my knowledge neither of the [Country and area extracts](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) does not support direct download through url. One needs to click at least on something.

Comment: Clicking on *Export* allows you to view the URL for downloading raw data.

Not sure what you mean with "Country and area extracts does not support direct download". http://download.geofabrik.de/ for example has direct download URLs you can use.

Comment: I learned something new again (about the url of the downloading raw data).
I need to download the data according to the openstreetmap bounding box boundaries. download.geofabrik.de does not allow that. This is what I meant.

Comment: That's true. However if you need this data just once in a while and/or the area is really big then an extract might be the better choice. There are various tools around for cutting the data to a specific bounding box. See [OSM file formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Splitting_one_big_file_into_different_geographical_regions) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @scai.
I owe you a beer for all of this help you gave me.

Comment: I'll take you up on that :)

Comment: In my experience, it's usually much quicker and easier to start with the pre-made extracts for a country or region, as scai suggested, and then clip them to the bounding box you're interested in.  With Geofabrik, for example, you can download roads (or other features) as shapefiles, which saves a lot of work trying to select out tags you don't want, or wrestling with osm2pgsql.